# I need help for autocompletion in a textbox with id and text

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am a beginner in asp.net and I'm trying to add a search bar with autocompletion.

I want the result to return a list of object, result of a stored procedure on two tables with more than 200.000 rows each (top 30 result for the autocompletion), with 2 fields : a label (Resultat) and an Id (IdRes).

I managed to call my function, I get my result, but the autocomplete popup does not show or in a wrong way.

Here is the code of my `_layout.cshtml`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - CLAP : le colloque du cinéma</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")


    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#navinput").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "Home/RechercheAutoComplete",
                        data: "{'term':'" + $("#navinput").val() + "'}",
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                                return {
                                    label: value.Resulat,
                                    value: value.Resulat
                                }
                            }));
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
             <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
...
                <div class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="formgroup">
                        <input class="form-control" id="navinput" name="navinput" runat="server" type="text" width="512" placeholder="Search..." />
                        <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search" id="navsearchbtn" runat="server" OnClick="navSearch" type="submit" />
                    </div>
                </div>
...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - CLAP</p>
    </div>


    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

So, with this code, It shows me a popup menu in the left top corner of the browser, instead of under my textbox and it displays the ResId instead of Resultat.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it ? I want the user to select a label but return the Id.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a datalist, with all the desired options? That way if you search, it will show all the possible options, depending on the current content.

```html
<input list="MyDataList"/>
<datalist id="MyDataList">
   <option>option1</option>
   <option>option2</option>
   <option>option3</option>
</datalist>
```

I suggest you have a `<div>` with an ID. Then you use ajax to call a PartialView (by ActionResult-Method) which creates the `<datalist>` element with all the options. Then in the ajax-result-function you can populate the `div` like this:

```
$("#IdOfTheDiv").html(result);
```

Or alternatively maby use this: http://easyautocomplete.com/ (Haven't tried it)

Comment: I should I've been more specific, the autocompletion is a result of an sql query in 2  tables with more than 300.000 rows each.

Comment: @glaudioman Well, that's a lot. But how exactly do you want to display the results. Becaus if you only want the first fiew, you could just queue the reults and select the top 100 matches.

Comment: I want to display the first 15 result depending of the string in the textbox. For now, when the text changed, it fire my method with the textbox string for parameter. My stored procedure select .. where .. like %value% and send the 15 first row (for autocompletion, the complete list is for the result page).

Comment: Well in that case you cloud just use the result (Your 15 top rows), and use JQuery to alter the page. You can have the solution with the datalist and everytime the textbox is changed you can clear the content of <datalist> an fill it with the new results. That sould work.

Comment: I try this tonight and I tell you if it works. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So technically you need to do is for Every Key Enter in **textbox**
for example

H of **"Hamza"** you take this 'H' from TextBox and make an Ajax call and make a function in controller to return **JSON** result by querying the database using SQL like query which when using C# we can use **LINQ**

```
var nameSuggestion = customers.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("H")).tolist();
```

So this Method will return the JSON result and you can then AutoFill Your ListBox with suggestions using **JQUERY** or **JAVASCRIPT**,So you Keep on typing for every Key-Down Data-Base will be queried and you will get the changed suggestion side by side when you put in the letters one by one 
H
A
M
Z
A
This is how i did in my project and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but my problem is not how do I get the result but how can I display it. My query works, I get the result I expected, but the pop up shows in the top left corner of the browser instead of under the textbox and I shows me the Id instead of the label.